# Emacsのマウスで選択した範囲を取得する

Tags: emacs, elisp

今までずっとマウスで選択した場合、その範囲がRegionとなっていると認識していたのですマウス選択が解除された後もそこに `region-beginning` が残るようで`elisp`が思った通りの動作をしてくれません。

選択してる行が存在する場合だけ`markdown-mode`で先頭にスペースを4つ追加するという処理をしたかったので

```
(defun indent-rigidly-4 ()
  (interactive)
  (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) 4))

(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "TAB")
  '(lambda () (interactive)
     (unless
         (eq (region-beginning) (region-end))
       (indent-rigidly-4))))
```

としたのですが、これだと選択を解除した後の`Tab`でも更にインデントがついてしまいました。
現在選択してる文字列・行だけを対象に処理するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既に emasaka さんの回答で解決済みかと思いますが、`interactive` を使って `region` 情報を得ることができますので `(region-beginning)` と `(region-end)` を使わなくても済みます。

```
(defun indent-rigidly-4 (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (indent-rigidly begin end 4))

(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "TAB")
  '(lambda (begin end) (interactive "r")
     (and (region-active-p) (indent-rigidly-4 begin end))))
```

`(interactive "r")` とすることで、interactive に呼び出された場合は `begin` と `end` に `region` の開始位置と終了位置が自動的にバインドされます。

Comment: (interactive "r")いいですね。
なお、define-keyの処理を質問文のコードではなく文面に合わせるには、条件に合致しない場合の処理（indent-for-tab-commandでしょうか？）があったほうがよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 `(and ~)` の部分を`(if (region-active-p) (indent-rigidly-4 begin end)(indent-for-tab-command))))`に変えたら期待通りの動作になりました。

Answer (score 2):

マウス等で選択状態にあるかどうかは、`region-active-p`関数で取得できると思います。

Comment: regionは存在するかどうか以外にactiveかどうかの状態を持つんですね。ただ、emasakaさんがコメントで述べられてるように選択範囲だけをインデント処理するのはまた別の関数を使うのが普通なんでしょうか。もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: `indent-for-tab-command`が選択範囲を認識するコマンドなのかと勘違いしてしまいました。単純に場合分けすれば良かったんですね。解決しました、ありがとうございます。